# Error response 404 (Samba server ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: http-status-code-404, samba

I have Samba version 4.7.6-Ubuntu.

```
[Public]
   path = /storage/share
   writable = yes
   browseable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   guest only = yes
   read only = no
   create mode = 0777
   directory mode = 0777
   force user = nobody
   force group = nogroup
```

When I create a folder in the directory I cannot enter that folder via a web browser.
I received text message:

> Error response
>
> Error code 404.
>
> Message: No permission to list directory.
>
> Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI.
>   Please advise?

Comment: Samba is for sharing files between computer at a desktop level, it is not a web server... I'm afraid there's a confusion or lack of details

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I understand what is samba and what is apache server. Maybe I did not explain all details here. I am opening samba server in a web browser via IP address (http://192.168.110.15:8888/JIRA_Attachments/test/) and I got that error, but when I create from a terminal via root user same folder, it works.